# Why is Update Manager non-responsive and why is my wireless off?

Tags: wireless, networking, update-manager

I am new in using Linux. The problem I'm having is with the update manager. I have it pinned to the launcher but when i left-click it does not respond. When i right-click it it responds by showing me the menu but i don't want to install all the available updates. My laptop is a MSI CR630.
I also have a problem with my wlan. It's saying that it is manually turned of but I tried everything i could think of but let's face it, I am noob. But I'm using linux for 2 months now and I don't want to go back to a cracked windows.

If you would like to help me with an answer please be as detailed as you can.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be really good if you did these in two questions. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: I thought that the both of them are related somehow...

Answer (score 1):

With the help of rfkill list i have managed to figure out that the hard unblocker was the combo of Fn + F8.
As for the other problem, still not solved. I mean that when i have updates ready i can't load the interface with them listed. I click it but it doesn't load. But I am able to right click it and then click the option install all updates. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you not want to install the available updates? Updates are a good thing, and unless you know that updates will break compability you should apply them. You can apply all updates from a terminal instead of the update manager by running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Secondly, please have a look at [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into), we need to know if your wireless card is detected at all. Has it worked before, or has it never worked?

If you help us get a more complete picture of your problem we can help you a lot quicker.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
it has never worked before (i only sr=tarted working with linux when i boutght this laptop

Comment: *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 6c:62:6d:19:38:b9
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: and it continues like this :                            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.2.0-25-generic-pae firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:fdfe0000-fdfeffff

Comment: Here's [a thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973201) by someone having problems with the same controller (ralink). Try searching here on askubuntu and on the ubuntu forums for things to try, for example `rfkill list` which is listed in the thread I linked can give you info on whether the interface is blocked or not. You know what controller you have now so just start googling :) also try the `firmware-b43-installer` package.